# Keep page position when update an DOM element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a long table with many rows and have to scroll down to see all of them. When I update the last row, the browser automatically scroll to the top of the page. How can I fix it?

```
<table>
   .....
   <tr>
       <td id='row_xxx'>

       </td>
   </tr>
   .....
</table>
```

and script

```
$("row_xxx").html("abc abc ab");
```

Comment: You need to post your jQuery code and at least a sample of the HTML before we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll guess you could use the window.scrollto() functionality.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp

Or jquery scrolltop

```
$("#row_xxx").scrollTop($("#row_xxx").attr("scrollHeight"));
```

Comment: Hmm... never seen that one before. But I guess they have a point there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scrillHeight attribute.

```
$("#myTable").attr(
{ 
    scrollTop: $("#myTable").attr("scrollHeight") 
});
```